# Querying Numeric TableName fails

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am able to query the table named "012012" within SQL, but when attempting to query it from a C# application, it will say incorrect syntax near '012012'. Within SQL I would use double quotes to query this table as it doesn't work without them. Here is the code I am using:

```
string query = string.format("SELECT rec FROM '"+012012+"' WHERE cust = 'custname';");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just "SELECT rec FROM 012012 WHERE cust = 'custname';"?

Comment: Did you try using [ ] around your tableName?

Comment: If your table is literally called "012012" and you are using an Integer 012012, when it is converted to a string it will become "12012"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, then it does not allow un-escaped identifiers to start with numbers.  So, you must use brackets like so [012012].  However, this is only part of your problem.  The other part is that you are trying to use a numeric literal, and convert it to a string, but this number starts with a 0.  This will get truncated by default and just become 12012.  So, your best bet is to just do this:

```
string query = string.format("SELECT rec FROM [{0:D6}] WHERE cust = 'custname';", 012012);
```

The `{0:D6}` tells string.format to make the decimal field 6 characters wide, and pad 0's if it's shorter (which it would otherwise be 5 characters).

In this case, however, you probably don't even need to do that.. unless you actually need to derive the table name from a number, and you can just do this:

```
string query = "SELECT rec FROM [012012] WHERE cust = 'custname';";
```

I would also strongly advise against even starting to write code like this, as it is prone to SQL Injection vulnerability, you should always use parameterized queries and prepared statements.  They're more work, but they are far safer.

Learning to write SQL code like this will form bad habits, which can be very dangerous later in your career.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a table name as `'012012'`. You don't even to use `string.Format` in your case. It will be useless.

If you wanna use `string.Format` with your table name, you can do it like;

```
string query = string.format("SELECT rec FROM [{0}] WHERE cust = 'custname';", "012012");
```

Comment: I undid my downvote because you improved your answer to the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using square brackets:

```
string query = string.format("SELECT rec FROM ["+012012+"] WHERE cust = 'custname';");
```

Brackets are required if you use keywords or special chars in the column names or identifiers.

Comment: @JordanJohnson - i'm not sure how that would resolve the issue, since that would generate a table named 12012 not 012012.